# how to assign backspace as back key

Tags: c#, winforms

I am Designing a windows form in which there is a picturebox which has back arrow image how to assign backspace key as direct shortcut to going back on previous form when current control is on form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the form property `KeyPreview = true;`.
Then use the `KeyDown`-Event of the picturebox like this

```
private void picturebox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Back) this.Close();
}
```